# How to add date and time from TextBox via DateAdd?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2016

I have a userform with two TextBoxes, one textbox (called `TextBox1`) is input for days, and the other TextBox (called `TextBox2`) is an input for time.

I would like to add the days and times to the starting point of `01/01/2022 00:00:00`.

For example:

```
TextBox1 = "5"
TextBox2 = "10:00:00"
```

I would like to add one day (value of `TextBox1`) to the starting day which is fixed (`01/01/2022 00:00:00`).

I use the following formula:

```
Range("A1").Value = DateAdd("d", Me.TextBox1.Value, "01/01/2022 00:00:00" + Me.TextBox2.Value)
```

I was expecting `06/01/2022 10:00:00`.

It gives me a Type mismatch error.

Comment: the string "5" is not the same as the number 5. DataAdd expects the second parameter to be numeric.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use *DateTime*, not text:

```
Range("A1").Value = DateAdd("d", Val(Me.TextBox1.Value), DateSerial(2022, 1, 1) + TimeValue(Me.TextBox2.Value))
```

Comment: Thank you a lot, I have been struggling now for 4 hours trying all possible ways.